# How can I use VBA to list all worksheets in a workbook within a string?

Tags: vba, worksheet

How can I use VBA to get the names of all the worksheets (or alternatively a maximum of three) within the active workbook to be returned as a string? For context, I will then use the string in naming the workbook when it is saved. I have figured out how to create a savename for the file using input dialogs and so on, so it's only a case of getting VBA to return something like "[Worksheet 1 name] and [Worksheet 2 name]".

Thanks so much!

Comment: By looping through all the worksheets and getting their names from `.Name` property?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Sub namesheets()

Dim wks as Worksheet, strName as String

For each wks in Worksheets
     strName = strName & wks.Name
Next

End Sub
```

You can also google "Excel vba loop through worksheets in a workbook" or something to that effect and find the answer very easily.

Also, this question was asked in some form on this website. See link... [Loop through subset of worksheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591442/excel-vba-how-to-loop-through-a-subset-of-worksheets)

Comment: Thanks for this. I do have a couple of followup questions - thanks to my poor knowledge of VBA, I must admit. Initially, how would I use this string? I currently have code which saves a file using strings: SaveFile = VendorCode & " - " & VendorName & " - " & ContentDate   - what would I insert in there to utilise this string? Lastly, would there be a way of inserting commas between the worksheet names? Thank you so much!

Comment: I would ask that you do a little diving into what you have. You are trying to build a string, and you have a string built out of variables and text (" - "). Continue on the basis of what I wrote and what you are already have and you will be able to make your string (Hint = a = Scott b = Holtzman -> strName = a & " " & b strName = Scott Holtzman. Please don't forget to mark your answer as accepted if you feel you got what you asked for.