# VBA: How To Reference ComboBox Object

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

I have created a lone ComboBox on the first worksheet in Excel. However, I can't find a way to reference its object.

I inserted a module, and one of my subs can successfully reference the following value:

Sheets("Sheet1").Name

However, the following is not available and throws an error:

ComboBox1.Value

Error message is: Run-time error '424': Object required

Can someone explain how to reference this ComboBox in my worksheet? Thanks

Comment: try : `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects("ComboBox1").Object.Value`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That depends on the type of combo box that you created:

- **Form Control**: `Sheets("Sheet1").DropDowns(1)`
- **ActiveX Control**: `Sheets("Sheet1").ComboBox1`

`Sheets("Sheet1").` can be omitted if the code is placed inside the VBA module `Sheet1`.

Also see [What is the difference between "Form Controls" and "ActiveX Control" in Excel 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15455179/what-is-the-difference-between-form-controls-and-activex-control-in-excel-20)