# Populate a combobox into a Userform with a selection of cells in the active sheet

Tags: vba, combobox, range, userform

I just started to use VBA into excel and I'm trying to create a User Form where I select data from the active sheet (the Userform shall be duplicated once I duplicate the sheet where it is included and all the reference  shall be to te active sheet):

- the Userform is named "SystemDesignUserForm"
- the actual sheet where it is included is named "System Design"
- the ComboBox is named "DIAComboBox" and shall list the data included into cells "w6:w33".

I tried with the code:

```
DIAComboBox.List = Range("W6:W33").Value
```

and also with

```
DIAComboBox.List = ActiveSheet.Range("W6:W33").Value
```

and with:

```
DIAComboBox.List = Worksheets("System Design").Range("W6:W33").Value
```

but it doesn't wotk: the combobox appear void.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Where did you put the code?

Comment: This should help with referencing combobox.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44096320/10365764

Answer (score 0):

You can try iterating through the range and populate:

```
'set worksheet
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("System Design")

'loop through and collect range
    For each c in ws.Range("W6:W33")
        With Me.DIAComboBox
            .AddItem c.Value
        End With
    Next c

    Me.DIAComboBox.SetFocus
```

Hopefully this helps.