# How to recreate Excel autofilter effect in different cells

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, excel-2016

I hope this makes sense...I've got a fairly simple Excel spreadsheet, and though I'm not sure if this is even possible, what I'm trying to achieve is at the top of the sheet to have a row of 4 drop-down lists that users can use to filter 
the data in the spreadsheet.

I want them to be able to select a criteria from a drop-down list of the column headings from the spreadsheet, and filter from values in that column, and a further 3 drop-downs, so they can filter data in the spreadsheet for up to 4 columns. In my head I'm thinking that it'd be a row of drop-downs, but thinking about it, it may need to be a two-stage process, first selecting the column heading and then the criteria to filter on for each of the possible 4 options (users wouldn't have to select 4 columns, but would need to be able to select up to 4 columns).

Basically, it's effectively recreating the Excel auto-filter in a different series of cells rather than at the top of each column (a couple of users have said that they feel that it would be more intuitive than searching for the little arrow on each column). I'd need the data to be filtered in place, rather than copied to somewhere else or displaying in a table or something.

Is this possible?

(btw - my test spreadsheet I'm trying different things on at home on my home laptop is using Excel 2016, whereas at work where the 'live' spreadsheet is, because we're rather behind the times, Excel 2010, so it needs to work on both versions)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, depends on how you wanna do it. You are descriping the process you have to do. 
What you need are 4 dropdowns, you have to fill them with your criterias, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29565846/how-to-populate-a-combobox). When the user selects something you can apply [`autofilters`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/office/ff193884.aspx)to the columns.

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned in my post that I've not a clue about VBA - it's not something I've ever used. Is there any way to do it without using VBA?