# Find Seprate Sheet name from 100 Workbook and paste into the Master File

Tags: vba, excel

Respected All,
My question is below

I have a 50 Workbook in a folder and in every workbook there is a separate Sheet name Call "Data". here i would like to loop form multiple workbook throw loop and find seprate "Data" sheet name in the workbook if there is a sheet called "Data" then Copy that sheet and paste into the Master Work book. is it possible in in VBA if possible please guide me how to do this.

Comment: Welcome Ajay to SO. This is a Q&A site. So, short answer is Yes, it is possible to do what you want with VBA. You can research a bit on VBA tutorials and even SO itself to get started. For example, here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba or here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20246465/how-to-copy-only-a-single-worksheet-to-another-workbook-using-vba Try them out and come back here if you have more questions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Loop through files in a folder using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba)

Comment: what is the folder path?

Comment: Hi @PA i have check this above all link but i am not able to find suitable answer i would like to find seprate sheet name in my 50 Workbook which name is Order i would like to find Order Sheet Name in all 50 Workbook if find then copy the data can you please help me Please

Comment: Hi @user1, I have save in my local directory called C:\Data in this i have save around 50 Workbook and in all 50 workbook there is Order sheet name

Comment: What kind of help you need? the linked SO questions contain possible solutions to your stated problems. Look at them, try them, and come back with a more precise question.

Comment: Hi @PA i have check link that you have mark but this is loop only file name i need to loop Tab name of 50 workbook can you please guide me how to loop throw tab name of 50 workbook

Comment: Research yourself !  Just a quick check on SO gave me this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1591442/how-can-i-loop-through-a-subset-of-worksheets